# How to remove object in JSON file via Linux command

Tags: json, linux

I have JSON file which is placed into Linux server. I want to delete partcualr object from second position onward.
Issues:-

1. Root element keep it and same object which is repeated in JSON file has to be removed.
2. how to append box brackets in JSON data

I tired `sed` and `awk` command but no luck

`sed '/"audit"/,/}/ d; /^$/d' sample_request.json >> test.json` -- It was deleting entire object instead of particular word.

**audit** -- Remove this object in json file from second position on wards.
**[]** -- This box brakcets are needs to append to file which is show as
 excepted output

**Actual :-**

```
{
  "audit" : {
    "audit number" : "123",
    "amount" : {
      "Amount" : -10.0,
      "code" : "abc"
    },
    "over" : 1
  },
  "audit" : {
    "audit number" : "234",
    "amount" : {
      "Amount" : 290.0,
      "code" : "xyz"
    },
    "over" : 5
  },
  "audit" : {
    "audit number" : "235",
    "amount" : {
      "Amount" : 270.0,
      "code" : "kdb"
    },
    "over" : 6
  },
  "id" : "test",
  "eid" : "1",
  "bcode" : "123",
  "wid" : "1234",
  "wsid" : "11",
  "ss" : 2
  }
```

**Excepted output like below:**

```
{
  "audit" :[{
    "audit number" : "123",
    "amount" : {
      "Amount" : -10.0,
      "code" : "abc"
    },
    "over" : 1
  },
   {
    "audit number" : "234",
    "amount" : {
      "Amount" : 290.0,
      "code" : "xyz"
    },
    "over" : 5
  },
    {
    "audit number" : "235",
    "amount" : {
      "Amount" : 270.0,
      "code" : "kdb"
    },
    "over" : 6
  },
]
  "id" : "test",
  "eid" : "1",
  "bcode" : "123",
  "wid" : "1234",
  "wsid" : "11",
  "ss" : 2
  }
```

Comment: Hi, forgot about json format , Does it possible to remove audit tag using sed or awk commond in linux, if yes please share full command so that will try at my end.

Comment: Have a look at [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/). Trying to process JSON with sed or awk is just a bad approach from the start.

Comment: @oguzismail True. I'm assuming the input is actually valid JSON - if it's not, then using any standard tools won't be possible anyway.

Comment: @oguzismail if the only bug is a repeating property it is valid afa `jq --stream` is concerned.

Comment: @oguzismail I only realised it now - the input is actually valid JSON. At first I thought that there was no closing `}` for the root object, but it was just misaligned. Remember that [keys in a JSON object are not required to be unique, they just SHOULD](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt) (section 2.2).

Comment: That said, anybody using non-unique keys in JSON objects should at least rethink what they're doing.

Comment: Hello Daniel, jq is out of scopr at our end. can we remove audit property which is repeating ? We have to achieve this through sed or awk only option. can you please help me out.

Comment: sed -r "s/.audit//" test.json -- i treid this option but it was deleted property entire file but my goal is it has to be start deletion from second occurrence on ward not first.

Comment: @SatyaRankiReddy : I'm sure there is a lot of tools that can help you. You most probably have Python or Perl installed - perhaps look into creating a simple script which would do what you're trying to? `sed` is really not the solution. If you really insist on using `awk`, at least use an [actual parser](https://github.com/step-/JSON.awk) to do the job. There also seems to be a [shell JSON parser](https://github.com/dominictarr/JSON.sh) available. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In sed, you can do something like:

```
sed -e '1,/audit number/s#audit".*#audit" : [{#' \
    -e '/audit number/,$s#"audit"\s*:##' \
    -e '{N;s#,\s*"id"#]&#;P;D}' input.txt
```

which roughly translates to:

1. between lines 1 and the first "audit number" substitute A for audit fields.
2. between the first "audit number" and the end, substitute B for audit fields.
3. use line joining to find ,[spaces]"id" and insert the ']' before it.

Working with JSON with string tools is very dangerous as changes in spacing and order that are irrelevant between programs exchanging JSON will mess up this style of parsing. It is usually better to do a minimal amount of fixing to get to valid JSON and then use normal JSON facilities in a favorite programming language.